# Get column name by student name

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Is it possible to get the column name of a table in a query? I'm using PDO

```
 stu_name      maths   science   music  art  

 John          done      done      -    done   
 Max             -       done      -    done   
 Peter          -        done      -     -
```

E.g.  How can I get subjects that has `John` not completed ( `-` )?
`music` should be the result.

This is where I am now. I do not know how to do it.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM coll_student WHERE stu_name = :name AND ?? = '-' LIMIT 1";
$stat = $connect->prepare($sql);
$stat->execute(array(':name'=>"John"));
$output = $stat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

Comment: this is poor table design Becky. It turns simple joins into the nightmare that you see below in an answer to deal with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this:

```
SELECT
  GROUP_concat(COALESCE(CASE WHEN maths   = '-' THEN 'maths'   END, ''), 
               COALESCE(CASE WHEN science = '-' THEN 'science' END, ''), 
               COALESCE(CASE WHEN art     = '-' THEN 'art'     END, ''), 
               COALESCE(CASE WHEN music   = '-' THEN 'music'   END, '')) AS SubjectsNotDone
FROM coll_student 
WHERE stu_name = 'John'
AND ((maths    = '-') OR
      (science = '-') OR
      (art     = '-') OR
      ( music  = '-')) ;
```

This will give you:

```
| SubjectsNotDone |
|-----------------|
|           music |
```

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f3337/1)

---

However, your table is not [normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). You can make it simpler and easier, and more performance wise, by creating a new table `Subjects`:

- `SubjectId`,
- `SubjectName`.

Then the table `coll_student` will be like this:

- `stu_name`,
- `SubjectId`- [**Foreign key**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) to the subjects table:

  ```
  constraint FK_SubjectId foreign key (SubjectId) references Subjects(SubjectId)
  ```
- `Status`: bit or int as flag for done or not (or other statuses if you have).

Then your query will be much simpler, something like this:

```
SELECT subjectname
FROM coll_student AS c
INNER JOIN Subjects AS s ON c.SubjectID = s.SubjectId
WHERE c.name = 'John' AND c.Status = 0;
```

- [**Updated SQL Fiddle Demo with the new design**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42fbb0/2)

Comment: Thanks for that additional bit. :D Can you explain `SubjectId - Foreign key to the subjects table.` Foreign key to subjects tables what?

Comment: @Becky it is a foreign key constraint, I updated my answer with updated sql fiddle demo with the new design.